# Swift - Nil error for date

Tags: ios, swift, null, nsdateformatter

I am reading data from Firebase and populating a local object with that data which also contains a validFrom and validTo attributes. Now when I am printing the validTo in the below code, it shows the date string but after the highlighted line, it has a nil value. This is really strange as validFrom still has the expected value.

Here is the function:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MiniPromotionTableViewCell

        let promotionEntry = self.promotionObjectsArray[indexPath.row]
        cell.titleLabel.text = promotionEntry.promotionTitle


        let properValidFromDate: UnixTime = promotionEntry.promotionValidFromInt!
        promotionEntry.promotionValidFromString = properValidFromDate.toDay

        let properValidToDate:UnixTime = promotionEntry.promotionValidToInt!
        promotionEntry.promotionValidToString = properValidToDate.toDay
```

> ```
>         print("Until here promotionValidToString has a value I want")
> ```

```
        let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"

        dateFormatter.dateStyle = .ShortStyle
```

> ```
>         print("Next line throws nil when setting date2 because promtionValidToString is nil")
> ```

```
        let date1 = dateFormatter.dateFromString(promotionEntry.promotionValidFromString!)
        let date2 = dateFormatter.dateFromString(promotionEntry.promotionValidToString!)

        cell.validityLabel.text = "From \(promotionEntry.promotionValidFromString!) To \(promotionEntry.promotionValidToString!)"

        if date2!.timeIntervalSinceNow.isSignMinus {
            /*date is earlier than now*/
            cell.promoStatus.text = "Valid"
            cell.statusImage.image = UIImage(named: "valid.png")
        } else {
            //myDate is equal or after than Now (date and time)
            cell.promoStatus.text = "Expired"
            cell.statusImage.image = UIImage(named: "expired.png")
        }

        return cell
    }

}
```

The print statements highlighted are what is happening and where. Anyone can spot the error?

Comment: Can you show the value of `promotionValidToString`?

Comment: 14/09/2016. This is same format exactly for date1 but that works well